# Remote Debugging in SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, eclipse, cloud-foundry, s4sdk, sap-cloud-platform

I am wondering how to remote debug a S4SDK/Spring 2.0.6 Java Application deployed in SAP Cloud Foundry.

I am using Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) and started the app in Debug Mode. The application will be restarted with the following environment variable: -Dspring.devtools.remote.secret=secret -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address=47822

The console output shows, that after startup an SSH tunnel has automatically been created successfully (as a prerequisite I have enabled SSH using cf enable-ssh).  and 'Successful remote access by 10.0.136.5:34858'.

After a few seconds, eclipse shows the message "Failed to connect to remote VM".

**How to enable remote debugging?**

Comment: Which buildpack are you using?

Comment: I am using sap_java_buildpack

Comment: I guess you're aware of this page, right? https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/1e7376fa1a8a4cefbed5c87693af4e6a.html

Can you describe how you've set up the SSH tunnel? Maybe use the verbose option to see any potential issues.

Answer (score 8):

This depends a bit on the buildpack you are using (see [this link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/1e7376fa1a8a4cefbed5c87693af4e6a.html)).

For the `sap_java_buildpack` you need to do the following:

1. Run the `jvmmon` in your CF container:

   ```
   cf ssh <app name> -c "app/META-INF/.sap_java_buildpack/sapjvm/bin/jvmmon"
   ```
2. In the opened CLI enter `start debugging`.
3. (Optional) Enter `print debugging information` to verify that debugging is enabled.
4. Exit the CLI with `q`.
5. To open the ssh tunnel enter `cf ssh <app name> -N -T -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000`.
6. With that you can connect to your application via `localhost:8000` by the usual means of your IDE.

As I have no experience with remote debugging in Eclipse I cannot help you with that part, in IDEA there is a special "Remote" Configuration where you can add the remote URL, so `localhost:8000` in this case.