# Fail to start application locally after enabling Spring Security

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to enable spring security to protect my backend services in SDK archetype project based on Spring according to the tutorial https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/.

After I start the application locally, an error message shows up - "Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set". Below is the stack trace of this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerTokenServices' defined in class path resource [com/bosch/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices]: Factory method 'resourceServerTokenServices' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.bosch.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerTokenServices' defined in class path resource [com/bosch/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices]: Factory method 'resourceServerTokenServices' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices]: Factory method 'resourceServerTokenServices' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES not set
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser.parseVcapServices(SAPVcapServicesParser.java:42)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPVcapServicesParser.<init>(SAPVcapServicesParser.java:30)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.<init>(SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:35)
    at com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPOfflineTokenServicesCloud.<init>(SAPOfflineTokenServicesCloud.java:27)
    at com.bosch.SecurityConfig.resourceServerTokenServices(SecurityConfig.java:47)
    at com.bosch.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e72219b.CGLIB$resourceServerTokenServices$1(<generated>)
    at com.bosch.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e72219b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$948b0fba.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.bosch.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e72219b.resourceServerTokenServices(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

The steps to reproduce the issue：

1. Create a fresh sdk archetype project based on Spring
2. Uncomment out all the code in SecurityConfig.java
3. Import all the security libraries
4. Start the application locally

The application is running well on SCP Cloud Foundry.

I know the root cause is the application is going to read Environment variable VCAP_SERVICES when initializing bean in SecurityConfig.java. But it cannot find it in local environment.

Is there any workaround if I want to run application locally?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316380/mock-a-https-destination-to-connect-to-system-behind-oauth2-authentication/58377838#58377838

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318790/how-to-run-downloaded-app-router-via-service-marketplace/53326776#53326776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, we've used extensively is to use a script locally which sets the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable similar like on Cloud Foundry (cf env ). I assume, this will satisfy the SAPOfflineTokenServicesCloud bean creation.

With that you can start the application locally, but NOT test your web application when the application is secured. Because in this case you need to call the endpoints of your web application with an Authorization header, which needs to contain a "valid" access token. A token is considered to be valid if it is not expired and if it is signed with a private RSA key, which matches the public RSA key, which is provided by the jwks token endpoint of the uaa as documented here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/74.4.0/index.html#token-keys

You have these options:

- For **integration testing**, you can fetch a fresh access token for your (test) user from the xsuaa service using this endpoint: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/74.4.0/index.html#password-grant. You can use also the java [token-client](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration/tree/master/token-client) lib.
- For **local testing** (w/o) Xsuaa interaction:

  - you need to generate a Jwt token using for example this [JwtGenerator](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration/blob/master/spring-xsuaa-test/src/main/java/com/sap/cloud/security/xsuaa/test/JwtGenerator.java) and
  - change as part of your VCAP_SERVICES environment your **verificationkey**, which matches to the private key, the token is signed with (e.g. the [JwtGenerator's public key](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration/blob/master/spring-xsuaa-test/src/main/resources/publicKey.txt)), e.g. "verificationkey":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BA...".
- For **unit testing**

  - you need to generate a Jwt token using for example this [JwtGenerator](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration/blob/master/spring-xsuaa-test/src/main/java/com/sap/cloud/security/xsuaa/test/JwtGenerator.java) and
  - you need to overwrite your SAPOfflineTokenServicesCloud as done [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-bulletinboard-ads/blob/solution-24-Make-App-Secure/src/test/java/com/sap/bulletinboard/ads/config/TestSecurityConfig.java#L14)

This should work (I've never tested that setup in combination with SAP Cloud SDK).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you specify how to set the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable locally using script?

Comment: yes, you can find one here: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-bulletinboard-ads/blob/solution-25-Make-App-TenantAware/localEnvironmentSetup.sh

Answer (score 2):

Update:
I just found out that we had a comparable question with an helpful answer before: [How to run downloaded App Router via Service Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318790/how-to-run-downloaded-app-router-via-service-marketplace/53326776#53326776)

---

As the security features heavily rely on the bound XSUAA service, as well as the fact that you need to access your application via an AppRouter, there is no easy/recommended way to start a secured application locally.

Comment: I am asking this question because I need to package my application locally and also run the integration test cases in the pipleline. The integration test cases are going to test the rest api I provided. If my application cannot start, the integration test case would fail.